# Laravel PDOException SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'forge'

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I am using Laravel to connect to MySQL database and got this exception:

```
PDOException
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'forge'
```

and this is my config.database.php

```
'mysql' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'localhost',
            'database'  => 'laravel',
            'username'  => 'Anastasie',
            'password'  => 'A@Laurent',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),
```

why is the error referring to `PDO` database? and why the `forge` database name? I have already changed it.

Should I do anything to tell Laravel that I am using MySQL database?

#### Update 1

I found this line
`protected $table = 'users';`
in my user.php file and I have changed it to 
`protected $table = 'user';` because the table in my database is `user` not `users`

#### Update 2

I wrote this in my Route

```
Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');
```

and I added `UsersController.php` in my controllers folder

and inside `UsersController.php` I have this:

```
class UsersController extends BaseController {

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $users = User::all();
        return View::make('users.index', compact('users'));
    }
```

and I call this url `http://localhost:8082/laravel/public/users/`

I am using Windows 7 with Laravel 4.2

Comment: do we have any environment configs setup?

Comment: Have you changed environment specific database configuration? Also, there is no such thing as PDO database. Laravel uses MySQL by default, unless you have changed it to other type (such as PostgreSQL).

Comment: @itachi I did change the username, password, and database name.

Comment: @kajetons I see this line `'default' => 'mysql',` in my database.php configuration file. I have never changed it

Comment: @AnastasieLaurent try to clear the cache with : php artisan cache:clear and try again and the pdo error comes from the fact laravel is using the pdo driver for mysql

Comment: @Freelancer I am so afraid of clearing the cache, maybe I have done something wrong. please check my updated question

Comment: @AnastasieLaurent as you want but your old conf could be still in the cache file.

Comment: @Freelancer Okay I will try. Could you tell me please how to remove that cache plz?

Comment: @Freelancer clearing the cache really helps. You are great. could you write your own answer in order to accept it please.

Comment: @AnastasieLaurent I wrote an answer, glad it helped you

Comment: All the below solutions are great. But sometimes they don't work because once you have run the "php artisan serve" command and then you go on to create the database and migrations server kinda not know that you have done these chnages so you need to stop the server by "Ctrl + C" and the re-run it again with serve command and it will work. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You have to clear the cache like that (because your old configuration is in you cache file) :

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

The pdo error comes from the fact Laravel use the pdo driver to connect to mysql

Answer (score 15):

1. First you have to Create your related Database.
2. Then:`php artisan cache:clear`
3. Now run `php artisan migrate:install`

Hope your problem will get resolved.

Comment: Thanks. These steps helped me "over the line" once I realised I was attempting to use the default port in both Laravel and wampserver. One of them needed to change!

Comment: I got this error after a phpMyAdmin timeout and trying to create database with the default 'laravel' name which already existed and without password in .env. I changed the name in .env, created the database manually and then ran php artisan ...

Answer (score 10):

Using phpMyAdmin (or whatever you prefer), I just created a database called "forge" and re-ran the `php artisan migrate` command and it all worked.

Answer (score 6):

write

```
php artisan config:cache
```

in your terminal and it will be fixed

Comment: Even using `config:cache ` instead of `cache:clear` has been suggested before.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to include  an explanation of how this works and why it is of solution to the problem described in the question. See [answer].

Comment: My vote for this answer. Also have renamed `DB_DATABASE` in `.env` and  `env.example` and stuck with old 'laravel' name in cash. Tried all from the page end . Finally this made it with `config :cache`

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you have an environment-specific config file somewhere that overrides the default database settings. Possibly **app/config/local/database.php**.

Comment: Hi, Do you want to give you all the database.php content ?

Comment: @AnastasieLaurent Yeah please post in original question

Comment: @Scorpion The user `Freelancer` helps me. I had to clear the cache. Now it is working.

Comment: Martin Bean, thanks for your efforts and time, but the user `Freelancer` helped me. Best regards,

Answer (score 4):

Note: Once it happened that I accidentally had a space before my database name such as `mydatabase` instead of `mydatabase`, phpmyadmin won't show the space, but if you run it from the command line interface of mysql, such as `mysql -u the_user -p` then `show databases`, you'll be able to see the space.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem...
If you have set your DB name and username and pass correctly in .env file and its still not working run the blow code in terminal:(this will clean the caches that left from previous apps)

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

and then run the command `php artisan serve` again (if you are running it stop and run it again)

Answer (score 3):

1. Stop the server then run `php artisan cache:clear`.
2. Start the server and should work now

Answer (score 3):

1. Stop the server then run php artisan cache:clear.
2. Change .env file DB_PORT=3308 (3308 For me)
   [mysql port](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vN4dY.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

I did all of them but didn't work, I find out should stop php artisan serve(Ctrl + C) and start php artisan serve again.

Comment: Not exactly a kinda solution wanted. But it worked for me. Wondering how it worked.. Crazy

Comment: I just noticed about my 2nd terminal that I also ran `php artisan serve` because of this so I closed the other and run `php artisan serve` again.

Answer (score 1):

If you've used Homestead, make sure the database name in your .env file below

```
DB_DATABASE=homestead
```

Is the same as the value in your Homestead.yaml file.

```
databases:
    - homestead
```

Answer (score 1):

first clear your cache using this command

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

Then restart the server using this command

```
php artisan serve
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What does this answer contain that isn't covered by the eighteen existing answers including the accepted answer? When adding answers to older questions it is important to point that out and to make sure that the explanation covers how and why the answer works as well.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the error was due to incorrect port number (the error is definitely due to incorrect credentials i.e. `host/port/dbname/username/password`).

Solution:

1. right click on WAMP tray;
2. click (drag your cursor) on MySQL;
3. see the port number used by MySQL;
4. add same in your Laravel configuration:

   - `.env` file;
   - `config/database.php`.

Clear cache
`php artisan config:cache`

Run migration
`php artisan migrate`

Answer (score 1):

Check your port in WAMP (it places on top of the phpMyAdmin) match with `DB_port` in the `.env` file.

My `DB_port` in `.env` is `3306`. My server port in WAMP (phpMyAdmin) is `3308` - you should match them.

Answer (score 1):

you need just create database or import your data by localhost  phpMyAdmin and don't forget the name should be same named

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Encountered this issue quite a few times, note that I'm running laravel via Vagrant. So here are the fixes that work for me:

- Try again several times (refresh page)
- Reload vagrant (vagrant reload)

You may try reloading your server instead of vagrant (ie MAMP)

Answer (score 0):

OK, found solution.

In the file database.php, by default, it comes the "mysql" part:

```
 'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```

all you need to do is change the values :

```
'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
```

by your database name (you must create one if you dont have any) and by that database username

like this

```
'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'MyDatabase'),
'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'MyUsername'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you do not have a duplicated `.env` file in the laravel folder. If it exists, delete it. Only keep the `.env` file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the name of the DB in the file .env (and if need in .env.example)
I solved my problem with this little correction.

Comment: Maybe you didn't notice, but the OP has mentionned that she changed her .env file.

Answer (score 0):

In my particular case, I *finally* realised that my phpMyAdmin was using port 3308 while Laravel was attempting to connect through 3306. so my advice would be to ensure you have the correct connection string!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my response to the problem described in the question.

in cmd write:

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

then try to do this code in your terminal

```
php artisan serve
```

note:
this will start again the server

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem for several days, it turns out if I created the db inside phpMyAdmin it wouldn't appear to Laravel,
so, I created the db through MySqlWorkbench, and it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

clear your Cache `php artisan cache:clear` and then restart your server `php artisan serve` `127.0.0.1:8000`

Comment: Your answer doesn't seem to be different than the accepted answer. Also, the question was asked and answered 6 years ago. Be sure to look at the date of the original question when answering. Please read [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

My APP_NAME variables  in `.env.example` and `.env` and `app.php`  were with space  e.g. The App . Surounding that by `'` and  `php artisan cache:clear` and setting new generated app key to APP_KEY variable through env files   and relaunching the server by  `php artisan serve` solved this issue

Answer (score 0):

In the fourth solution this question was answered but I prefer to answer again to explain this differently .
I make my database in **phpmyadmin** that is **http://localhost/phpmyadmin** and the problem was solved .this is my code :

```
<?php

$servername = "127.0.0.1";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "myDbn2";

try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

echo "Database created successfully<br>";


$sql = 'create table if not exists fruits (id integer  , name text , color text 
, price float) ;';

$conn->exec($sql);
echo 'the table created successfully </br>';


$sql2 = 'insert into fruits values (1 , "apple", "red" , 23.2);';
$conn->exec($sql2);

echo 'insert was successfully';
} catch (PDOException $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
}

$conn = null;


?>
```

The code make a database then make a table and insert a record in it .
if you don't make your data base in **phpmyadmin site** you get the exception
also you **don't need** to use sql statement **CREATE DATABASE name ;** and it works without it .

Answer (score 0):

`php artisan config:cache`
that command fix my 1049 database not found.

Answer (score 0):

Every body have mentioned to `php artisan cache:clear`. Sometimes it doesn't work.
But in my experience after clearing the cache simply delete the database and create it again.Then run this again

```
php artisan migrate
```

Surely it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because MySQL could not access the database configured in the environment file.

To resolve, I simply created the database that MySQL and the app needs and all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

in my experience I had like this message error ,and i tray all of this solution but nothing to become good ,whay because my fault is i unstall Xampp and i read install again and i forget to create new Database with table that's way in the message say : "Unknown database" it's not exist simply ,now what i do is:

- install Xampp (if you have problem in it ofcaurse)
- i create now database  + table
  short you don't see the error message again .
  NB ( I'm new in Programation )
  < my conseil to be patient when you write your code >

Answer (score 0):

Remove files from this path bootstrap\cache\

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem,  I see the my databases list the name of my database which doesn’t exist.

I create the database at the same name manually then I run this command it works for me.

1. create database in phpmyadmin
2. php run artisan

Answer (score -3):

sometimes its because `DB_CONNECTION=mysql` and you want to use SQLite database.
A solution to that is to make `DB_CONNECTION=sqlite`. hope it helps

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=C:\xampp\htdocs\jbtibl\database\database.sqlite
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```